# How to set focus to a window in GTK3?

Tags: c, gtk3

I have 2 windows: the first is the main one and the second is the *window_histogram* one. I want to click on a certain area of the first one, and then the second one gets the focus.
I have this in the first window, so when it is clicked, these lines are executed:

```
gtk_widget_set_can_focus (combobox_widget,TRUE);
gtk_window_set_focus(GTK_WINDOW(window_histogram),combobox_widget);
```

However, the second window, does not get the focus.
I have also tried this:

```
gtk_window_set_focus (GTK_WINDOW(window_histogram), NULL);
```

And this:

```
gtk_widget_set_can_focus (combobox_widget, TRUE);
gtk_widget_grab_focus(combobox_widget);
```

But none of them have worked and the second window remains unfocused. What can I try?
(Feel free to require more details).

Comment: In the documentation page it suggests you to try gtk_widget_grab_focus "To set the focus to a particular widget in the toplevel, it is usually more convenient to use gtk_widget_grab_focus() instead of this function." https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-focus

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [gtk_window_present](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-present). This will show the window and bring it to the front. Note that this may not work properly on Windows.

Comment: The window is not focused on LXDE after calling this function. Is that a bug in LXDE? Anyone knows any workaround?

Comment: @saeedgnu Can you open a new post, complete with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and link it back here?